# How do I add a description to search on Bower.io?

Tags: bower, bower-register

I have a component: [`chrome-extension-async`](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync) published to both Bower and [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-extension-async).

When I search for it on [bower.io](https://bower.io/search/) it finds the package, but it doesn't find the description.

My [`bower.json`](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync/blob/master/bower.json) has a `description` property.

[libraries.io](https://libraries.io/search?q=chrome+extension+async) finds the component on both NPM and Bower, but the latter has no description (either from the `json` or the [readme](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync/blob/master/README.md))

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also by checking [the code](https://github.com/librariesio/libraries.io/blob/8f2eca4733ee6a962602353264c4f8552ba00ded/app/models/package_manager/bower.rb#L51) of libraries.io responsible for bower packages, it looks like everything is fine from this perspective. If you had changed your github repo name in the meantime though, that might very well be the issue.

My best bet would be a caching issue. If you had published it previously without description, libraries.io or bower.io might hold a cache of some fields like that, and I dunno really when it could be invalidated, you can also see you have 0 stars here which is not up-to-date.

I'm sure you already tried to bump the version, since as I can see from the bower.io api your did a last version on April 16. If you didn't thought, you might want to give it a try.

What I would advice you is to try changing your name to `chrome-extension-async-tmp`, and see if it gets picked up. If it does, that means it's something related to caching. In this case, you could (depending on your user-base) un-publish and republish the package, so the description gets picked up again.

After a simple clone and rename of your package, I published it on bower and 1 day later it was showing on the search results of both [libraries.io](https://libraries.io/bower/yolo-extension-async-test) and [bower.io](https://bower.io/search/?q=yolo-chrome-extension-async), with the correct descriptions. As you can see in their [github.rake](https://github.com/librariesio/libraries.io/blob/master/lib/tasks/github.rake#L16) they are syncing repositories that have never been synced. Hopefully since [#1080](https://github.com/librariesio/libraries.io/issues/1080), they added a button to manually trigger a re-sync of a library if you are logged on the site (if no sync has occurred less than 24 hours ago). So I think that's what you're looking for.

[image: img]

Comment: It's had a description and `README.md` since the first Bower release. I don't really want to re-publish the package under a different name, especially when I don't know why it doesn't work now. Even if that works anyone using the Bower package will have issues.

Comment: I'm just talking about re-publishing your current project under a different temporary name to try things out, not as a final solution

Comment: cheers for trying that, it seems to have the [same problem](https://libraries.io/bower/yolo-extension-async-test) though.

Comment: Hum I can see the description now on both libraries.io and [bower.io](https://bower.io/search/?q=yolo-chrome-extension-async). I published it yesterday, so I think they have a cron syncing packages every 24h, and maybe the process to grab the content of the bower.json is pretty slow.

Comment: I think this was a bug that they've now fixed. I first published the package to bower on March 10 and had tried Resyncing before I raised this question. I think this is [a bug](https://github.com/librariesio/libraries.io/commit/e75725663d84e0e9c9f3a404c2d85a71509eb433) they fixed.

Comment: I see well in any case glad to see the problem is gone ;)

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be fixed now, and this is what I did:

- Click on "Make a Suggestion" on the libraries.io page in the bottom right hand corner.
- This goes to a form: https://libraries.io/bower/chrome-extension-async/suggestions
- Updated that with the same information as on here.
- Wait a few weeks.

Now https://libraries.io/bower/chrome-extension-async has the full README and the search at https://bower.io/search/ picks up the description.

I think this was actually a bug in libraries.io and it resolved when they [fixed it](https://github.com/librariesio/libraries.io/commit/e75725663d84e0e9c9f3a404c2d85a71509eb433).